# Нужна ли запятая в сокращённом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

> Так ты, оказывается, (...)! Были на днях у Ивановых(,) и там узнали.

Пропущено "мы" перед "были" и "об этом" после "узнали". В полном варианте ясно, что запятая не нужна, потому что "мы" не повторяется. Кто-то может спросить, зачем же она здесь, и, возможно, окажется совершенно прав.

Но я сомневаюсь. Мне кажется, что в пользу запятой может быть то, что предложение можно разбить на два практически без изменений:

> Были на днях у Ивановых. Там и узнали (об этом).

Answer (score 1):

**Были на днях у Ивановых и там узнали.** *И* — союз, он соединяет однородные сказуемые (были и узнали); запятая не нужна.

**Были на днях у Ивановых, там и узнали.** *И* — усилительная частица, однородные сказуемые идут через запяую (были, узнали).

Comment: Спасибо! Получается, основной аргумент не в пользу запятой — отсутствие подлежащего во второй части? И раз его нету, ничто другое сложносочинённым уже не сделает всё предложение, да?

Comment: Подлежащее хоть и отсутствует, но подразумевается, и оно - общее для обоих сказуемых (мы были и узнали), сказуемые явно однородные. Поэтому нет причин считать это  ССП.

Comment: Спасибо! Я понимал, что подразумеваемое подлежащее общее, но думал, вдруг нужна запятая, раз разбить можно. Но чувствовал, что маловероятно.